# How to access value in class' atribute in models.py Django

Tags: python, django

I would like to change the username and question using my function in views.py. This is my models.py:

```
class Choice(models.Model):
    username = models.ForeignKey(Users, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Questions, null=True,  on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    answer = models.CharField(null=True,max_length=50)
```

I would also like to change the username inside choice using this line:

```
 if username == str(Users.objects.latest('name')):
             Choice.objects.username = Users.objects.latest('name')
```

Is there something like `Choice.objects.something` that might retrieve value in 'username' and allow me to change it?

Comment: But here you change it given it is already the "latest" one. Can you explain *what* you aim to do? Note that `username` does *not* store the name of the user, the database stores the primary key, and `mychoice.username` will lazily retrieve a `Users` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use variables to store the Choice instance, set the username, and then call `Model.save()` to write that to the database.

```
choice = Choice.objects.get(whatever criteria you use to get the instance)
choice.username = Users.objects.latest("name").username
choice.save()
```

Comment: I did exactly what you said and weirdly, I got atribute error 'Choice' object has no attribute 'username'. I checked my database at admin view and it's there. Other options work, like question, question_id etc. Any idea why is that?

Edit:
Actually I forgot to update my console, I will try everything once more